# Is there an alternative to Google Chrome Extension's floating window panel?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, panel

I know that panels are being taken out of the chrome extensions, and that it is no longer possible to use them as floating "always on top" windows. I want to achieve something similar to Evernote's Web Clipper chrome extension. I think they are using panels right now. Could someone please suggest an alternative that I can use to achieve something similar?

Comment: [Evernote extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc) simply adds DOM element into the page. [Evernote app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web/lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol) is simply an [app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/), not an extension. FWIW you can abuse chrome.notifications API to display small floating windows with buttons and a "requires interaction" flag, and re-display them when those get hidden by chrome.

Comment: also, panels have been fully gone from chrome for several months now.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more specific. I meant the Evernote Web Clipper, which is definitely an extension. I will edit the question to reflect the same